# Android - Download Unsuccessful and Parsing Error while trying to download and install .apk from server

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, android-download-manager

The goal is to update my app without using the google play store. I’m trying to download a .apk file from a server and then install it programmatically. I’m currently getting an error that the download is unsuccessful and that there was an error while parsing the package. I have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions requested at runtime. I had to go into the tablet's settings to give permission to “Install unknown apps”. I cannot get REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES to be requested at runtime.

If I change the fileName and update URL to get a .txt that I store in the same folder on the server as the .apk AND comment out “.setMimeType()” I can download and view a .txt file.

- Have the updates to Android Studio made older tutorials or examples of this outdated?
- Is there a new or better way to download .apk’s from servers programmatically?
- Is the lack of  REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission at runtime what is preventing my .apk from downloading?
- Any advice on how to fix my code?

Here are some code snippets to help

**gradle:app**

```
android {
    compileSdk 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "farrpro.project"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 30
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void hasInstallPermission() { // runs in onCreate() 
        if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES}, 1);
        }
    }


void downloadAndInstallUpdate(){ // runs when users accepts request to download update
        String fileName = "update.apk";
    // example of update’s string
        update = “https://myserver.net/update.apk”;

        //set download manager
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(update));
        request.setTitle(fileName)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                .setDescription("Downloading")
                //.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
                .setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");


        // get download service and enqueue file
        final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
        System.out.println("Max Bytes: "+DownloadManager.getMaxBytesOverMobile(this)); //returns null


        //set BroadcastReceiver to install app when .apk is downloaded
        BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
                System.out.println("Is download successful: "+ manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadId)); //returns null
                System.out.println("Mime: "+manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId)); //returns application/vnd.android.package-archive

                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                File file = new File(ctxt.getExternalFilesDir(null) + fileName);
                Uri downloadedApk = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctxt, "farrpro.project.provider", file);

                install.setDataAndType(downloadedApk,
                        manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
                install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                try {
                    startActivity(install); 
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error in opening the file!");// this never prints 
                }

                unregisterReceiver(this);
                finish();
            }
        };

        //register receiver for when .apk download is complete
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the server had restricted download types. My code worked more or less after that setting was changed. I ended up needing to change the intents in my broadcast receiver so that after the download was completed the new .apk would immediately install. Here are the changes I made to make the code posted work.

```
 final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent1) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadId), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                try {
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error in opening the file!");
                }

                unregisterReceiver(this);
                finish();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running on Android O or newer, you have to allow unknown app sources for your app.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (!context.packageManager.canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).apply {
            data = Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", context.packageName))
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```